# What happen when we do multiple malloc for allocating memory to a single destination pointer?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

What problem the program has, with regard to memory usage? What happens when you `malloc` the same pointer multiple times? Does it create new memory in heap every time, the pointer would point to the new memory and the old memory would then be wasted?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = 111;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr =-234;
    printf(“\n%d\n”, *ptr);
    free(ptr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: > Does it create new memories in heap every time,the pointer would point to the new memory and the old memory would then be wasted?

spot on - you answered your own question

Comment: It would help to avoid saying "malloc a pointer".  `malloc` allocates new space each time it is called. You might then store the address of that space in a pointer variable.

Comment: You don't "`malloc` a pointer"!

Answer (score 18):

In your code

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 111;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

The call to second `malloc()` stores the return value into the *same* variable. This way, you're overwriting the previously returned pointer. So, the second `malloc()` (storing the returned pointer in the same variable) causes [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

You lose the actual pointer previously returned by `malloc()` and have no ways to `free()` that. So, you're right, the old memory is *wasted*, (*Note: not `free()`-d*).

FWIW, every call to `malloc()`(*provided success*) gives you a *new* memory area. It does not *create* a memory as such, but it returns a pointer with requested memory size which can be used and `free()`-d later.

To add to this, a(ny) modest memory checker tool will scream for the above code. Here's one of the widely-used one, [valgrind/memcheck](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 3):

> What problem the program has, with regard to memory usage?

You are using or allocating un-neccessory memory using malloc. You could have used single malloc.

> What happen when you malloc the same pointer multiple of time?

Each time you store the pointer of some memory block, allocated by malloc, in same pointer `ptr` , the `ptr` will point to most recent.

> Does it create new memories in heap every time

Yes each time you call malloc, a new block of memory is allocated.

> the pointer would point to the new memory and the old memory would
>   then be wasted?

A block of memory would still be reserved under your task or process until you explicitly free it, which you can't do after pointing the `ptr` to another block in this case. It would be free only when the task or process is ended, but before that memory is being leaked.

Comment: The last answer, `No`...can you explain? How does an inaccessible memory is _not_ a wastage?

Comment: `It would be free only when the task or process is ended, causing leaking of memory.`... you're contradicting yourself, if it is getting free-d how is there a _leak_?

Comment: By being wasted, I interpreted as 'Free', The memory would be there and no other malloc in this process can allocate that until freed. That's what I wanted to say before.

Comment: FWIW, a `free()`-d memory is never _wasted_,, at least that is what I know.

Comment: E.g. the plateform I am working has a heap of 64k for tasks. So if I am doing same thing again and again, a times come when I can't allocate more memory, so appearently I am using just one block out of heap, but in actually all the memory has been leaked. So when OS closes this task, all the memory would be freed then.

Comment: Inaccessible objects **are** leaks. Once an object becomes uncaessible from the program code, it leaks. Not after the program terminates. The final free'ing is not part of the C language anymore, but a "courtesy" of the environment (not fully self-less, though).

Comment: @SouravGhosh The memory is indeed wasted if it cannot be used by any other process. In this case, the process would keep wasting heap memory until it runs out its quota and the process crashes. Then the OS would free up all the memory held by this process. But until then all this memory is unusable by another process. Hence termed memory-leak

Comment: @VivekVijayan Correct.but what did you try to explain?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was replying to your comment "_a `free()`-d memory is never wasted,, at least that is what I know_"